# Way to get unique user location from Azure User Graph

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

To get list of unique user location from all users in the Azure AD

Comment: The ”unique user location" you mean membership in a specific group?

Comment: Do you mean actual physical location (e.g. from the sign-in activity), registered office location (e.g. from the user attributes), or, like @SunnySun-MSFT asks, abstract location in groups or the organization?

Comment: From the User attributes..registered office location

Answer (score 0):

You could use `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$officeLocation = 'location'` 
 as the global admin to get a list of unique location in Microsoft Graph Explorer.

[image]

And the required permissions:

[image]

Comment: @ Sunny sun - Here we are passing "us" as parameter to the query, i was looking for something to get list of distinct office location across AD

Comment: If your office location is us, you can just replace the `location` with "us" just like I tried, and then it will return all the users that the office location is us.